# Go: HTML cannot find css file

Tags: html, css, go

So i'm writing a web application in Golang. The html references a `css` file like so: `<link href="/css/index.css"...`, but the `css` file is never found!.

Here is the bummer though, i have a couple of `css` files and they are all in the same folder, and they all work!.

If i create another `css` file and name it `index2.css` and copy the contents of `index.css` into `index2.css`, this works perfectly, but for some reason, the name `index.css` does not work!

Also, when i go to the link `http://localhost:8080/css/` this list all my `css` files. If i click on any of them, it opens up perfectly except `index.css`; i get a 404 not found.

This is really strange, any idea what could be the problem?

All files in css folder:

[image]

index.css not found:

[image]

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="/css/index2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/img.png"/>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/scroll.js"></script>
</head>
```

When i like to `<link href="/css/index2.css" rel="stylesheet"...` i can see the css style on my page. When i link to `<link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"...` i can't.

index.css exists in my folder:

[image]

EDIT

It works now. I think it was a permission issue. I deleted the old `index.css` and created a new one and it works now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Code you must show.

Comment: Difficult to answer without code source.

Comment: i'm sorry. The code is just plain html, didn't  think it would be useful. But i have just uploaded some code as well as some images

Comment: You should check your permissions for index.css if you're using a mac or linux.

Comment: is the path correct?

Comment: Hmmm. It was probably a permission issue. I deleted the old one, and created a new one and it works now. Funny thing is i did this before and it still didn't work. Oh well, welcome to programming i guess...

Answer (score 1):

Did you mark the css folder as static in your server side script? Try running this code from your go web server and see if you could access those css files.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web/content/css")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I'm not sure if I got your folder structure right, you might have to modify "./web/content/css".

Answer (score 0):

May be this problem is because of -

1.Temp file, try to find index.css~ file.If using Ubuntu then go to the css folder and press `ctrl+H`. then you will see the temp file if it is there.

2.May be path is not correct.

3.May be file got corrupted, try to delete and create new index.css

4.Provide your source code to debug your issue.